# Pinned message appears pinned, but is not actually pinned

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-stars, chat-pins

I stumbled across what I think is a bug:

[image: It's true, too!]

This is after refreshing the page. Here's the sequence of events:

1. Message posted, and starred by a few people (including me)
2. Stars cleared (not by me)
3. Pinned (by me)

Comment: [Theme](http://userstyles.org/styles/97667/soda-chat), [Image hiding script](http://stackapps.com/questions/4344/ponies-hide-unwelcome-images-in-chat), [More stars script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3260/more-stars-userscript-that-frees-up-room-so-you-can-see-more-starred-messages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that was a bug. This particular order of events violated the assumption that any pinned message also has at least one star. Pinning usually implies starring, but this was broken for the case that you had earlier starred the message and the stars had been cleared. Going forward this will work correctly, and I have fixed this particular message (which was the only instance of such a problem).